# After ILMerge Assembly.GetAssembly and similar throw ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, reflection, ilmerge

i use ILMerge via code, using the following snippet to get my merged .exe (Windows Console Application)

```
var ilMerge = new ILMerge();
ilMerge.SetInputAssemblies(files);
ilMerge.OutputFile = outputFile;
ilMerge.TargetKind = ILMerging.ILMerge.Kind.Exe;
ilMerge.DebugInfo = true;
ilMerge.SetTargetPlatform("v4", "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319");
ilMerge.Closed = true;
ilMerge.Merge();
```

worked like a charm until i do something like that in one of the merged assemblies:

```
Type[] tlist = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes();
```

this throws a **ReflectionTypeLoadException**

this Exception contains an Array called "LoaderExceptions", filled with a single **LoaderException** with the following Message

```
"Could not load type '<>c__DisplayClass38' from assembly 'test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'CleanWhitespace' has no implementation (no RVA)
```

CleanWhitespace is a static function in one of the assemblies i merged, does nothing special...

No problem to call it directly in the merged .exe

same exception gets thrown using...

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
Assembly.GetAssembly();
```

what is going on ? any help of what i do wrong ?

bit puzzled here...

Comment: What app type console || winforms || wpf || other...

Comment: What is the message of the exception? Does it have inner exception?

Comment: @Peuczyński I don't think that's relevant here. Assembly is an assembly, it should matter what type of application it contains.

Comment: Try using ILMerge with WPF or read about the topic

Comment: indeed, first exception contains a LoaderExceptions array, filled with the following exception: Could
 not load type '<>c__DisplayClass38' from assembly 'test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'CleanWhitespace' has no implementation (no RVA).

Comment: CleanWitespace is a static function, does nothing special and resides in one of the assemblies i merged

Comment: type is a windows console application...